# How to customise view android sdk, calendar view

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Im first time work with UI. I know about customising standart things (list, table or something other). I need to do as in the example below. Calendar view. Who know tutorials/samples like that ? Sorry, but i never works with UI in android SDK.

[image]

Comment: You could look at [designing the view for a calendar app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912473/android-designing-the-view-for-a-calendar-app/33923513#33923513) for a full sample of a given day and go from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quoting** from **[CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)**

> CalendarView class is a calendar widget for displaying and selecting
>   dates. The range of dates supported by this calendar is configurable.
>   A user can select a date by taping on it and can scroll and fling the
>   calendar to a desired date.

**Android does not offer any calendar view in the SDK**. That is a big loss from the developer’s point of view. There are lots of situations where it would be beneficial to display days of a month and provide some option for the user to choose the day.

1. One solution is to use a  **[3rd Party Component](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-calendar-view/)**.
2. The second one is to ***implement one by your own*** .

Courtesy goes to **[How to implement CalendarView in Android](https://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/)** .

Please check

1. **[Android calendar view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702998/android-calendar-view)** .
2. **[Designing the view for a calendar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912473/android-designing-the-view-for-a-calendar-app)** .

Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this library, [material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview).

Have a look around the way they implemented the calendar and maybe you could customize it for your own design.